# Selenium css from parent to locate child

Tags: css, r, selenium

For a html structure like this

```
<div class = 'detail'>
    <div class = 'info'>...</div>
    <div class = 'text'> child1 </div>
    <div class = 'expand'>
        <div class = 'info'> child2 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I only want to locate the first "class = info" directly under the parent tag "class = detail", that is, "child1". But the following selector--

```
remDr$findElements(using = 'css', value = '.info')
```

--gives me both of child1 and child2. Unfortunately I cannot use index to solve this problem. Is there a way to locate child1 by specifically pointing that its parent must be 'class = detail'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `child 1` element use following `css` selector.

```
remDr$findElements(using = 'css', value = '.detail>.text')
```

Or if you want to get first `info` class with `parent detail` then try this

```
remDr$findElements(using = 'css', value = '.detail>.info')
```